# Centring the whole web page (on a really wide site)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page that is wide (3078px) and pretty long too (1540px). 
The page has a large div containing 6 divs inside it on 3 columns and two rows (each row a separate div itself).
When the page loads, it displays the top left div (box1) in the top right corner, with the option to scroll down or right to see the rest of the content.

I'd like to make it be centered on load, that is to say, I would like the middle column (box 2) to show in the middle of the page when loading, with the option to scroll left and right for the rest of the content.

Is there any script or CSS/HTML combo that would allow me to select what will be displayed in the browser on load? Essentially, what I'm trying to do is similar to centring the whole of the body within the browser window. I was considering attaching an anchor with a name to the middle div (box2), but I still wouldn't know the Javascript to make it select that div as the top left to load on. 
Please let me know if this is a bit confusing, I can make a sketch to explain what I mean if that could help! (The jsfiddle link is below)

HERE IS THE CSS:

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align: center;
    background:black;
}
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4, #box5, #box6 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px red solid;
}
#above {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:3078px;
    height:770px;
    background:transparent;
}
#below {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:3078px;
    height:770px;
    background:transparent;
}
#mainbox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:3078px;
    height:1540px;
    background:transparent;
}
```

AND THE HTML:

```
<div id="mainbox">
    <div id="above">
        <div id="box1"></div>
        <div id="box2"></div>
        <div id="box3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="below">
        <div id="box4"></div>
        <div id="box5"></div>
        <div id="box6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a JS fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/KyMet/

A similar question would be (to remove the pain of horizontal scrolling) – If I have a really long page, which scrolls vertically, how can I get it so that it loads with the bottom of the page in the browser window, so that, practically, you need to scroll up to see the rest of the content?

Comment: Why don't you inplement this with some slider? It will show only the content you whant and you will be able slide between the other content?

Comment: Inside each div there will be other content too, which is interactive (images with onhover/onclick effects) so I don't think the slider thing will work. If you have some links to that, maybe I can have a look?

Comment: What you are describing is a horizontal web site instead of a vertical one. Horizontal web sites are not that common and are usually avoided but still do exist and actually come out pretty impressive BUT at the hands of a experienced developer. I suggest you read the following.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

Comment: http://www.awwwards.com/25-great-horizontal-layout-websites.html

Comment: http://www.designyourway.net/blog/inspiration/awesome-examples-of-horizontal-scrolling-websites-33-examples/

Comment: http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/40-of-the-best-horizontal-scrolling-websites

Comment: just a question, is the above and below suppose to be on two rows?

Comment: Hey!I've actually worked with horizontal websites before, I know what they are and how to make them work nicely. What I don't know is how to make a web page load something else than the top left corner first, because typically scroll is from left to right, with all the content to the right. It's that I am trying to change!

Comment: I was talking about something like this: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/8/

Comment: @Dejan.S – they're supposed to be the two divs that make up the top (above) and bottom(below) column.

Comment: @drip – that wouldn't work with what I am trying to achieve. Basically, I just want a really wide/ long page that is centered on upload, allowing the user to move across the page, left, right and down. Does that make sense?

Comment: @drip A similar question would be (to remove the pain of horizontal scrolling) – If I have a really long page, which scrolls vertically, how can I get it so that it loads with the bottom of the page in the browser window, so that, practically, you need to scroll up to see the rest of the content?

Comment: Then how about moving the scroll of the page in the center via JS on doc ready?

Comment: @drip – I think that could work, I'm just no JS master! If you could help me with the script for that, I could vote it as the answer! Thank you!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5QBnJ/ The styles are from here: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/ just made it so it would be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some query to pull this of.

**EDIT** 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2CbsY/)

```
$(function(){
    //total width of your wrapper
    var totalWidth = $('#mainbox').outerWidth(true);

    //width of the user browser
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    //calculate the middle
    var middle = (totalWidth - width) / 2

    window.scrollTo( middle, 0 );
});
```

**YOUR CSS**
I would also recommend you to clean up your css, there is a lot of unnecessary properties there. You can choose to use this

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4, #box5, #box6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    border: 1px red solid;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: aqua; /* only for demo */
}

#above {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
} 

#below {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}

#mainbox {
    padding: 0;
    width: 3078px;
    height: 770px;
}

/* For modern browsers */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.clearfix {
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use jQuery scrollto library

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/